# Is there any predictive way to watch for Hard Drive controller failure?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I'm not asking about sector errors or platter failure.  I'm asking about hard drive controller failure.

I've twice now had hard drives just quit working due to hard drive controller failure (not motherboard controller, the actual drive on board platter controller).  I use a product called 'HD Tune Pro' to check my drives on a regular basis, and I had no reported errors of any type, and then one day the drive is just dead.

I know for a fact it's a controller failure, because last time this happened I sent the drive to a hard drive recovery service, and paid to have it analyzed to find the problem.

It would be nice if there was a way to watch for the health of the controller, it's annoying as heck to just have controllers fail in the hard drive with no notice.  The one that died today was backing a VM, which of course, then crashed the VM, which caused other problems.

I've not been able to find any products or any way to analyze the health of a device on board controller.   The one that died today, was testing perfect this weekend with no failures and no problems of any type.   It's not a new drive, I've had it for 3 years, long enough that it shouldn't be a manufacture defect, but not too long where it's 'old'.  I generally always pitch my hard drives at about 5 years, so I'm right in the middle of what I would consider an average life on this drive.

Comment: Did you change the hard drive to get things working, or did you replace the motherboard?

Comment: This is a server with 9 x 4TB drives on it.   I generally tend to stick with nothing higher then 4 TB drives, just for this exact reason.

One of them contains VM's I use for emulating other servers for network testing.  That one just disappeared and of course, my VM's went away.    The server continued to function just fine otherwise.

I did the standard 3 finger salute, brought up MMC, rand a couple of hard drive utilities, nothing could find it.

I pulled it out, put it on a second machine, that machine could not see it either.  I don't even get an entry in MMC/Disk Management for it.

Comment: Sounds like the disk is dead, but does a replacement disk work well?

Comment: Yes, the replacement works fine.

But my question, is there a way to see the 'health' of the circuit board on the drive, so that I can get the drive out before the board fails?  Much like I can watch the health of a platter, and pull the drive out when the platters start throwing errors.

Comment: Measuring the health of or trying to predict the failure of electronic devices is highly problematic. At the present time this is more in the realm of science fiction than science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information published by the disk firmware is via the SMART data.
Any disk test you run on the computer, is implicitly also a test of the disk controller.

A good disk-health monitoring program will compare small variations in the SMART data
of the disk in order to warn on suspicious changes.

If you are worried about your disks, you should get such a disk monitoring
product, and perhaps run periodically some test of each disk, watching for
any SMART data variations.

I cannot recommend here a monitoring product, but see the article
[Best Free Hard Drive Health Monitoring and Diagnostic Programs](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-health-monitoring-utility.htm)
for a list of such free products with reviews, but which does not cover
commercial products.

Comment: Thanks, that's already what I am doing, and it did not give me any warnings.